# Why CSS rotated element is not aligning with container?

Tags: html, css

I want to stack these two elements on top of each other. I wanted the text to align in the center of the popup container, but I can't seem to do it with a rotated element.

```css
.popup {
  background-color: #f48277;
  width: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30vh;
  border-radius: 70px;
}

.popup-text {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 43vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .popup {
    width: 60px;
    height: 170px;
  }
  .popup-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">

</div>
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
  <p class="popup-text"> Save 20% |</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest putting everything inside the same container, so your HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="popup">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
    <p class="popup-text"> Save 20% |</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Aligning two different elements can get messy very quickly when they don't share the same parent.

You can use `writing-mode: vertical-rl` to rotate the text. Additionally you can use `transform: rotate(180deg)` to flip the text as well:

```css
.popup-text {
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

You can then use `display: flex` on the container to center the text both horizontally and vertically:

```css
.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
/* simple CSS reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup {
  background-color: #f48277;
  width: 70px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30vh;
  border-radius: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .popup {
    width: 60px;
    height: 170px;
  }
  .popup-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
    <p class="popup-text"> Save 20% |</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because you needed to put text inside a parent div and rotate the parent div not the text itself.

That's why text wasn't stable inside the div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.popup {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: salmon;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 32vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.popup-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .popup {
    padding-top: 9px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .popup-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-text popup">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Save 20% |</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just going to throw in my two cents:  if it were me, I'd make the banner horizontal, put everything in it like normal, and then rotate the whole deal 90 degrees:

```css
.popup {
  background-color: #f48277;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 70px;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 70px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.popup-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .popup {
    width: 170px;
    height: 60px;
    right: 60px;
  }
  .popup-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
    <p class="popup-text"> Save 20%</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your " transform-origin: top right " approach. It looks very tidy 